# DataFrame manipulation function/method

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have a df looks like

```
A    B
1.2  1
1.3  1
1.1  1
1.0  0
1.0  0
1.5  1
1.6  1
0.7  1
1.1  0
```

is there any function or method to calculate cumsum piece by piece, I mean for every consecutive B value 1, calculate cumsum, in the above example it should be

```
A    B    C
1.2  1    1.2
1.3  1    2.5
1.1  1    3.6
1.0  0    0
1.0  0    0
1.5  1    1.5
1.6  1    3.1
0.7  1    3.8
1.1  0    0
```

many thanks,

Answer (score 2):

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

text = """a  b
1.2  1
1.3  1
1.1  1
1.0  0
1.0  0
1.5  1
1.6  1
0.7  1
1.1  0"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=True)

c = df["a"].cumsum()
mask = ~df["b"].astype(bool)
s = pd.Series(np.nan, index=df.index)
s[mask] = c[mask]
c -= s.ffill().fillna(0)
print(c)
```

output:

```
0    1.2
1    2.5
2    3.6
3    0.0
4    0.0
5    1.5
6    3.1
7    3.8
8    0.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach (which may be slightly more general) is to groupby the consecutive entries in B.

First we enumerate the groups:

```
In [11]: (df.B != df.B.shift())
Out[11]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8     True
Name: B, dtype: bool

In [12]: enumerate_B_changes = (df.B != df.B.shift()).astype(int).cumsum()

In [13]: enumerate_B_changes
Out[13]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    3
8    4
dtype: int64
```

And then we can groupby this Series, and cumsum:

```
In [14]: df.groupby(enumerate_B_changes)['A'].cumsum()
Out[14]: 
0    1.2
1    2.5
2    3.6
3    1.0
4    2.0
5    1.5
6    3.1
7    3.8
8    1.1
dtype: float64
```

However we have to multiply by df['B'] in this case to account for 0s in column B.

```
In [15]: df.groupby(enumerate_B_changes)['A'].cumsum() * df['B']
Out[15]: 
0    1.2
1    2.5
2    3.6
3    0.0
4    0.0
5    1.5
6    3.1
7    3.8
8    0.0
dtype: float64
```

*If we wanted a different operation for entires neither 0 or 1 we could do something different here.*

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super versed in numpy, however the code below should help.

It goes through and if `b` is 1 continues to add to the cummulative sum, otherwise it resets it.

```
df = [
(1.2, 1),
(1.3, 1),
(1.1, 1),
(1.0, 0),
(1.0, 0),
(1.5, 1),
(1.6, 1),
(0.7, 1),
(1.1, 0)]

c=[]
cumsum=0
for a,b in df:
    if b == 1:
        cumsum +=a
        c.append(cumsum)
    else:
        cumsum = 0
        c.append(0)
print c
```

And it outputs (with rounding issues, which shouldn't happen in numpy):

```
[1.2, 2.5, 3.6000000000000001, 0, 0, 1.5, 3.1000000000000001, 3.7999999999999998, 0]
```